# How to get iframe contentWindow height in cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser

i want to auto adjust my iframe height according to their content but in same domain it's work properly with contentWindow.height but in case of cross domain its permission denied for accessing iframe dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For modern browsers you can use the [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) function to communicate between the iFrames belonging to two different domains.

There are also several jQuery plugins that wrap `window.postMessage` with older URL hashing techniques for browsers that don't support `window.postMessage`. It makes the usage of the technology transparent to the end user.

You can look at the following page (and probably borrow the javascript you need) from here:

[Lutron - Ballast Selection Tool](http://www.lutron.com/Service-Support/Technical/Design-SelectionTools/Pages/LEDDimmerMatrix.aspx)

The tool with the dropdowns is actually being loaded from a separate domain into an iFrame. The iFrame is then dynamically resized based on the height of the inner content.

Comment: I second the use of postMessage. Here's an easy example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606920/cross-domain-iframe-resizer/6940531#6940531.